# Database with blank cells

Tags: excel, database

I am trying to write a database that has 5 fields that the user may not need to fill.  When the user leave a field empty and the data is saved it causes the next entry to not be placed in the proper place due to the   This code will find the next empty cell as it should but not the cell that correlates to the data needed.
This is an example of the code I have written so far.
Example

```
Name   Device   Notes     IMEI     Tag      Date      Phone
John    Iphone   none      333      22      3/11/22    3939393939
Jim     Iphone             222      777     3/11/22    3344554323
Steve   Iphone             655      777     3/11/22    8878877678
```

In the example the last field for "Notes would be "C2" and the field I need to be called is "C5".

```
enter code here
Sub record_data()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For y = 6 To 140
    If Range("a" & y).Value = True Then
        staff = staff + 1
    Else
    End If
Next y

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to store " & staff & " names in Database", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then 'Exit Sub

For x = 6 To 140
   If Range("a" & x).Value = True Then
       Sheets("Database").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("b" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("c" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("d" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("e" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("f" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("g" & x).Value
       Sheets("Database").Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("h" & x).Value
       ' Sheets("Database").Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheets("Entry 'form").Range("e" & x).Value
   End If
```

Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Comment: Don't get the last row of every column. If you have a mandatory field, then use the last row of that field for every other column. If not, you'll need to find the highest row count and use that on every column

Comment: I thought about trying that but I wasn’t sure how to code it.   If I use the same format

Comment: Yes A col will always be constant.    I thought about trying that but I wasn’t sure how to code it.   So how do I use the same format.    Sheets(“Database”).Range(“A” & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1) and allocate that into my different column’s row number ?

Comment: Use `MyLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` (i.e. assign the value to a variable and use that (`Range("A" & MyLastow)`, `Range("B" & MyLastow)`, and so on)